# How do I replace a specific string in a 2d array?

Tags: python

I'm making a program that Identifies if a blank tile exists or not. I already have a code in my 2d array which is

```
arr2 = [['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' 'E' 'A' '#' 'L' 'E' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' 'P' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' 'P' 'E' 'A' 'K' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' 'L' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' 'E' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']]
```

I want to replace the # which is I labeled for the blank tile into one of the letters in the alphabet(A-Z). I already made a code that replaces the blank tile.

```
for i in arr2:
    for j in i:
        if j == '#':
           i = [j.replace('#', 'A')]
```

But for some reason it is still a # not an A. How do I replace the #(blank tile) in the given array into an alphabet? Also, how do I make a pop-up message so that players can just type an alphabet to replace for the # which is the blank tile?

Comment: you're missing a whole bunch of commas to make this valid, python, please fix it accordingly

Comment: `arr2 = [["A" if j == "#" else j for j in i] for i in arr2]`

Comment: Thank you so much, Rakesh!!.

Comment: Keep in mind that the solution of @Rakesh creates a whole new list and is therefore much less performant than iterating over the elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enumerate your array to change the value at a specific index.

```
for i, row in enumerate(arr2):
    for j, cell in enumerate(row):
        if cell == '#':
            arr2[i][j] = 'A'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the contents of the variable `i`, not the element of the array from which it came.

Answer (score 0):

you have to enumerate the data instead of just looping over it so that you can get the index of the item and replace it.

```
for xindex, x in enumerate(arr2):
    for yindex, y in enumerate(x):
        if y == "#":
            arr2[xindex][yindex] = "A"
```